# Will running nohup without & make the script stop when connection to remote server is lost?

Tags: php, nohup

I am running a script `nohup php /var/www/html/foo.php` an immediately i hit enter,it gives me `nohup: ignoring input and appending output to`nohup.out'`

My script is processing mysql records using pdo

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=odesk', 'root', '');
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id,msisdn from new_tableu limit 91471,10");
$sth->execute();

while($result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
}
```

Does this mean once i internet disconnects,my script too will stop?.

I could run my script in the background with `nohup php /var/www/html/foo.php &` but its running forever which is not what i want.

Comment: Maybe use a cronjob to stop and run the script as per your liking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is save to run it as:

```
nohup php /var/www/html/foo.php
```

There will be no interruptions when you are disconnected.

My advice is to try **[screen](http://www.rackaid.com/blog/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/)**, since this way you can disconnect then reconnect and check the script output

```
screen php /var/www/html/foo.php
```

This way I was running bunch of scripts that take few weeks to finish and each day I checked the progress.